# Index if not exists using bulk processor in elasticsearch

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to index a document if it doesn't already exist in elasticsearch. I am using `BulkProcessor` when indexing my documents and using `Requests.add` action. I will have the exact same id sometimes, does it not add automatically, but update?

P.S. Update is not a requirement, it can stay as is.

P.S.2 I am trying to integrate a user's past tweets into [elasticsearch-twitter-river](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-river-twitter)'s user stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you index a doc with the same document id then it will do an update. Otherwise it will add a new document.

In other words, if you `PUT` a doc to `{index}/{type}/{id}`, then it will always update (overwrite) the document with that id. If you `POST` a doc to `{index}/{type}` then in general Elasticsearch will generate a new document for each of your POSTs. That is, unless you [mapped a document field to the `_id` field in mappings](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-id-field.html).

It seems that the [Twitter River uses the PUT method with explicitly specifying the id](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-river-twitter/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/river/twitter/TwitterRiver.java#L635) so tweets with the same id will probably be overwritten.